# What's the big deal with Nd:YAG rods?

Tags: laser

I see the prices of Nd:YAG rods for lasers, and could someone explain why they are so expensive?

Do they need to be mono-crystalline or something? 
Will Nd:YAG laser work with amorphous/poly-crystalline rod?

Comment: Nd:glass is amorphous (obviously, it's glass). That's what they use in [NIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ignition_Facility). I don't know how the price and performance compares. Generically, high-peak-intensity laser parts have exacting specifications because defects and impurities can lead to bad things and vicious cycles: Light absorption can cause further damage, reduced mode quality can cause hot-spots, that can damage not only the rod but everything else the beam touches.

Comment: Why do you think the price is so outrageous? I priced a few and they don't seem out of line for a synthesized material, especially something that is a bit of a niche item. Compare the $/volume to something like synthetic diamond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first question, but the answer to the second one seems to be [no](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925346701002178), at least for poly-cristalline.